# Why did the height of the navigation bar change back to the default after backgrounding?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I set the height of the navigation bar to 55 in `viewDidLoad`, but after the app enters the background and becomes active again, the height goes back to the default 44.

What can I do?

Comment: How are you creating it and which class owns it (are you adding it as a subview?)

Comment: Maybe you can paste some code of how you set the height